# Synchronizing time within workgroup

Tags: windows-7, time, ntp

I have workgroup consisting of three Windows 7 computers without access to Internet. My wish would be to synchronize time across all by making one of them NTP server.

Is there any free NTP server out there that can run as a service and that can serve as reference for other Windows 7 computers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Meinberg NTP Software didn't work for me on Windows 7 and I could not find any other service that would, I created my NTP server.

Application is available at http://blog.jmedved.com/2010/07/ntp-server.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Meinberg NTP Software](http://www.meinberg.de/english/sw/ntp.htm), which appears to be configurable for Windows 2000 up to 7. According to the website, the software can also run on 32- and 64-bit versions of Windows.

Comment: Seems promising - I will check it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work. It has problems installing itself as service on Windows 7.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'll try to look further and see.